# Drawing Textures with OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing a 2D game for Android and i'm using the framework which has been told in the book which named Beginning Android Games by Mario Zechner.So my framework is well designed and using OpenGL 1.1.It's similar to libgdx.

When i put my textures adjacent each other in my 2d surface,there are some spaces size as 1 px.But this problem only occur on my tablet.There aren't a problem like this on my phone.It's like in this picture:

[image: my problem]

What can be the problem?I can't fix it from one week.

UPDATE:

```
      batcher.beginBatch(Assets.ground);
      konum =(int) (dunya.myMan.position.x/500);
      for(int i=konum;i<8+konum;i++)
      batcher.drawSprite(500*i, 61, 500, 122, Assets.groundRegion);

      batcher.endBatch();
```

Comment: Please show all relevant matrix setup. I didn't find the source for `batcher` (probably an `AndroidGraphics` instance).

Comment: Here is my framework:http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fch09-jumper%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fbadlogic%2Fandroidgames%2Fframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you're translating your quads by non-integral values, which can cause textures to get sampled off-center, and can cause some artifacts like that.

If you make sure that all your 2d translations line up with screen pixels, I think you won't see the problem anymore.

Comment: What you mean with "non-integral values"?

Comment: @droidmachine: I mean values that are not integers. Don't translate a quad by 1.75 pixels. Make translations only 1, or 2, or 3 pixels, etc.

Comment: I should have also mentioned that you need your orthographic projection dimensions to also match the number of pixels on the screen. What's your projection set up like? @droidmachine

Comment: Yes i'm using orthographic projection.